# How would you go? ________ plane?

Tags: grammar, articles

You have to help me on this fill in the blank in this fill in the blank you have to use the preposition

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Please take a look at https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. This question should include some information about what you've already tried and why you still need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respected Ayyan,
It should be by.

> How would you go? **By** plane?